# Are Attorney General Special Agents real?

Tags: castle

In Castle season 5 episode 23, Beckett and Castle investigate a case alongside a Special Agent who works for the Attorney General's Office. I did a bit of searching and from what I found, it seems that there are Special Agents employed under the various departments of the state and federal governments but there are no Special Agents that are employed directly under the Attorney General in the USA.

> The season 5 finale ends on a cliffhanger which is also based on this.

So, is the Attorney General's Special Agent a real thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_agent), most branches of the United States government have "special agents," including the Department of Justice (DOJ), which is headed by the Attorney General. Thus, having a special agent for, or from, the Attorney General is real.

There is also a page directly for the [State of California's DOJ Special Agents](http://ag.ca.gov/monthly_feature/about.php) that give an overview of what they do, at least for their state.  In fact, there's many more links for individual states as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a real thing. For example, I am a Special Agent working in the Investigations Division of the Office of the Attorney General in my state. We are sworn Criminal Investigators with full Police powers and come from extensive law enforcement backgrounds. I am assigned to investigate major felony crime and our office handles a very wide variety of criminal cases including drug crimes, weapons crimes, fraudulent ID mills, murder for hire, cold case homicide, white collar crime including medicaid fraud, public corruption, etc. I am aware of other states that have Special Agents under the Attorney General and would be willing to bet most states have something similar. It is a fantastic job by the way, the work is demanding, interesting and the people I work with are top notch.

Comment: I just realized that I did not answer your question correctly. I believe you were asking if there are Special Agents working for THE Attorney General as opposed to the states Attorneys General??? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well, yes. I was asking about the US Attorney General as thats what is mentioned in the storyline of the show.